# CSS animation:How to make the image object bounce back seamlessly?

Tags: html, css, animation, gif

**Demo:**
http://www.suanle.lol/move.php

In the animation demo you can see that when the egg just at the point of bouncing back, it flashes out for a second then flashed in. This makes the animation broken. So I wondered why this is happening and how I could fix it?

If you want to check the Gif:

[image: Egg]

Actually not just limited to the .gif, the problem occurs for any format of picture.

code is below:

```css
#egg {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 50px;
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 6.4s;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*animation: pulse 5s infinite;*/
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-left: 10px;
    /*width: 300%; */
  }
  49% {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 350px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 10px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="egg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke7wO.gif">
```

Comment: this is because of the moment it moves from `scaleX(1)` on `49%` to `scaleX(-1)` on `50%` of the animation

Comment: change 49% to 49.9%..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , This looks much better, changed **`49%`** to **`49.9%`** and it enhanced it a bit, the problem was this **`1%`** of the **`6.4s`** duration of animation is still noticeable which makes it "flashes".

by reducing this difference from **`1%`** to **`0.1%`** the period needed to transform from `scaleX(1)` to `scaleX(-1)` is not noticeable

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/rpzq5ts9/2/)

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(231, 143, 128);
  width: 310px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#egg {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 50px;
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 6.4s;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*animation: pulse 5s infinite;*/
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-left: 10px;
    /*width: 300%; */
  }
  49.9% {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 350px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 10px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="egg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke7wO.gif">
```